What are the guidelines regarding Mass outside of a Church setting?
I was talking to a rather hardcore TLM'er last weekend who, when it was mentioned that we're having an all-city Mass next week held in an amphitheater outside of our courthouse (which I thought was cool) that only in emergencies - like a time of war - is it licit to have mass outdoors like that. I was like "we're at war with the culture" and he was like "mhmm", well anyway, the conversation didn't go so well.
In any event, the previous weekend, I attended a TLM outdoors at camp and the week before I went to Mass several times in the Lucas Oil Stadium (Holy Ground now, next time Taylor Swift plays, I guess).  In any event, there's gotta be some rubric around it.  Is this just a "spirit of Vatican II" abuse that I've been frog-boiled into or is this actually something permitted by the US Bishops and is unique to the USA (but strangely ubiquitous) or is this a thing that can never be done under any circumstances?

"several times in the Lucas Oil Stadium" You were at NEC?

@eques yeah, were you? I posted on meta to see about a meetup.  Maybe in 2033!

In various parts of Germany and Switzerland Mass is "traditionally" held outdoors on the Feast of Corpus Christi. Here is a picture of Cardinal Woelki of Cologne celebrating Mass on this feast day in 2016 in the plaza in front of Cologne Cathedral. I do not know how old the custom is. My childhood straddles the switch from pre-Vatican 2 to post-Vatican 2 liturgy, but my recollection is hazy. I think outdoor masses on Corpus Christi were already a thing pre-Vatican 2 but I am not sure.

@PeterTurner Yes, I was there.

The Codex iuris canonici from 1983 says something about this:

Can. 932 §1. The eucharistic celebration is to be carried out in a sacred place unless in a particular case necessity requires otherwise; in such a case the celebration must be done in a decent place.
§2. The eucharistic sacrifice must be carried out on a dedicated or blessed altar; outside a sacred place a suitable table can be used, always with a cloth and a corporal.

So the normal case is to celebrate in a "sacred place" (a church, a private chapel etc.) and on an altar. But if there is a "necessity" ("necessitas") in a particular case, any other "decent place" is also possible. Than an altar is not obligatory (there are portable altars), but a "suitable table" is enough.
If there is a necessity the priest has to decide – he does not need the approval of his bishop or an other authority. A "necessity" is more than a "just cause" (often required in canon law), but is not bound to particularly grave causes such as emergencies.
So if there is no (big enough) church for the congregation, it is clearly possible to use another room or celebrate outside (so the General Instruction of the Roman Missal, n. 288). If it is only for the special atmosphere of a mass in the garden (I often attended such masses), one can argue if there is really a spiritual "necessity".
There are special provisions in can. 933 CIC for masses in a not-Catholic church.

Before Vatican II this was possible too, only under stricter conditions. The more important change is, that today an altar stone is no longer strictly needed. The Codex iuris canonici from 1917 says:

Can. 822. § 1. Missa celebranda est super altare consecratum et in ecclesia vel oratorio consecrato aut benedicto ad normam iuris, salvo praescripto can. 1196.
§ 2. Privilegium altaris portatilis vel iure vel indulto Sedis tantum Apostolicae conceditur.
§ 3. Hoc privilegium ita intelligendum est, ut secumferat facultatem ubique celebrandi, honesto tamen ac decenti loco et super petram sacram, non autem in mari.
§ 4. Loci Ordinarius aut, si agatur de domo religionis exemptae, Superior maior, licentiam celebrandi extra ecclesiam et oratorium super petram sacram et decenti loco, nunquam autem in cubiculo, concedere potest iusta tantum ac rationabili de causa, in aliquo extraordinario casu et per modum actus.

Normally the mass is celebrated in a church on an altar (§ 1). Some people (I don't know, who) have the privilege to use a portable altar by law or by special Apostolic indult (§ 2): they can say mass on any suitable place, but not on sea, and on a sacred altar stone (§ 3; the portable altars contained a stone). In extraordinarial circumstances the ordinarius (normally the bishop) can license to celebrate on any suitable place (but not in a bedroom) on a sacred altar stone (§ 4).
In 1963 the competence of the bishops was extended: they now were able to permit the celebration according to can. 822 § 4 CIC/17 in case of a just cause, for permanent cases a grave cause was needed ("ex iusta causa, habitualiter autem solummodo ex causa graviore", P. Paul VI., MP Pastorale munus, I n. 7). The new missal in 1970 already had in core the regulation later in can. 932 CIC/83. There was some discussion, if there should be an approval of the local ordinarius, but it was seen as unnecessarily complicated.

Literature: Althaus, in: Münsterischer Kommentar zum Codex Iuris Canonici, hrsg. von Klaus Lüdicke, Ludgerus Verlag (38. Lieferung Juli 2004), can. 932.

There are all sorts of reasons why someone might have Mass outside, beyond mere emergency. True, the most common reason might be that the celebrant is a military chaplain accompanying a group of Catholic soldiers to offer prayers and sacraments for them, but that is not the only conceivable reason.
Priests ought to say Mass daily (they are technically not under any obligation), but they may find themselves in situations where that would not be possible in a church building. For example, say a group of priests are going on a retreat for a few days together hiking in the Rocky Mountains. There's no consecrated building here. But the priests still ought to say Mass. So, they can bring a portable altar with them to celebrate.
For an historical example, Bl. Raymond of Capua refers in his The Life of Saint Catherine of Siena to a papal bull that gave him and some of the other Dominican friars permission to take a portable altar on the road specifically so that Catherine could receive communion whenever she wanted. There was no emergency here. Catherine could have missed communion on, say, a Wednesday while she was traveling between two cities. But she didn't want to, and the Pope saw it fitting to give her permission to receive even on the road, meaning a Mass would need to be said outside.
I wasn't able to find anything specifically allowing or prohibiting outdoors masses in the GIRM, though it seems clear the consecrated church building is the ordinary space for Mass. But we already knew that. Since I know that saints in history were given special permission to celebrate outside when there was no emergency, I'm inclined to think this is not an abuse, but that permission from a competent authority is necessary. I also think there needs to be a sufficient reason for it, though not necessarily an emergency. Having Mass in the stadium because there are tens of thousands of Catholics in attendance at the National Eucharistic Congress seems to me like a sufficient reason. But we are venturing into opinion.

What if a priest already said mass that day in a regular setting (thus fulfills his obligation), but then he goes hiking with a bunch of Catholics and the group thought it cool to have mass at the summit of the mountain?  Is that allowed?  (By the way, I'm not making this up; I see this as the annual practice of a group of 3rd order Dominicans in their annual hiking activity).

"Priests must say Mass daily" No, they don't. That has actually never been required as an obligation of ordination.

@GratefulDisciple apart from grave circumstances, a priest is ordinarily only allowed to do 1 Mass per day, 2 on Sundays/Days of Obligation. The Bishop can approve a 2nd (3rd on Sundays/Days of Obligation) beyond that requires approval of the Holy See.

@GratefulDisciple may I ask which Dominican province you are in?

@jaredad7 It's not where I live, the one I came across is this one but googling around, it seems other chapters do the same, like this one from Connecticut.

@eques thanks, I've changed my answer.

@GratefulDisciple sadly a number of Dominican provinces don't do what they ought anymore, or I suppose in this case do what (it seems like) they ought not.

@jaredad7 what's your evidence that Dominican provinces don't do what they ought to?

@GratefulDisciple our Troops of St. George group (who ought to be the uber conservative Catholics,) has had our chaplain come and say Mass for us on camping trips.  I think there should be an aesthetical difference between saying Mass at the summit of a mountain (for taste) and at camp (for necessity), but doesn't look like canon law covers matters of taste.

@PeterTurner I see.  Just found out that Bl. Frassati after whom the Frassati Hikes are named is about to be canonized next year !

@PeterTurner: Psalm 95:4 "and the mountain peaks belong to him". I would suggest the explicit wording makes the mountain peak more appropriate than base camp.

@eques personal experience. I'm a lay Dominican and our provincial council, well, let's just say there's a lot of silly drama, and a lot of editing of official documents all the time. And I know of other provinces that do things correctly. The biggest issue is the lack of encouragement to do penances, which was the whole reason our order was founded: penance for the success of the preaching. That seems to sadly be somewhat universal nowadays.

@jaredad7 That some communities aren't doing what they ought to do should surprise no one. It's a reality of a fallen world. But in this case, the comment seems more like detraction. No particular evidence has been outlined that what GratefulDisciple described is necessarily a fault.

@eques in general, you're not supposed to celebrate Mass outside of a consecrated space. That's the evidence that what was described was a fault. Also, it can't be detraction on my part since I'm very intentionally not revealing any particular persons or even particular communities. You don't know which province I belong to.

@jaredad7 and yet you don't cite Canon Law nor a rubric to that effect especially since you appear to be assuming a gravity of the fault. You are correct that you didn't identify a particular community, but that doesn't excuse the point I was making. Namely, it is entirely irrelevant to this conversation whether some particular people had bent the rules (no evidence was offered that any particular one had). If one were talking about a particular community, a comment about their lax interpretations might be appropriate.

@eques as I said in the answer I wrote, the GIRM appears to make the assumption that Mass should be said in a consecrated space, since it doesn't make any provision for Mass said in a non-consecrated space.

@jaredad7 Your intuition is correct if you acknowledge that absence of a prohibition is not a permission (unlike common law), but nor does it follow that an omitted prohibition necessarily is a grave fault.

@eques granted, it may not be grave.
